# Slow file operations, possible I/O error but chkdsk says OK

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk, directoryopus

I've recently faced a strange problem. I use Directory Opus file manager that suddenly started to report an I/O error when trying to copy files onto one of my disks. The Windows Explorer did copy those files but it was extremely slow.

I run chkdsk on this drive (ca. 300GB) and it took it over two days to complete! However it reported no errors found.

I run Hard Disk Sentinel that says the drive is OK.

But the files still read and write extremely slow! Can anyone advise me what to do? I have a spare space I am copying my files for backup now but should I get rid of this disk? Or can I try to "heal" it somehow?

Many thanks for your ideas!

Comment: I would try the acronis drive monitor (http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/) and to confirm that it is OK. It's free

Comment: Thanks! I installed it and it reports drive health at 88%, which seems fine. At first the only problem it reported was relocated sector count which amounted to 6 (not too many I believe, yet it marked it red). But then a completely new windows appeared in SMART status listing three big numbers (sectors?) with a comment "Degradated".

It was when there was a read operation running on that disk. When it ended it got back to normal SMART window report.

Well, it looks there is a problem somewhere indeed...

Comment: Well, degradation means the hard drive is degrading. I would back up now as my guess is the hard drive is going to die!

Comment: Well, I am copying the files to a backup storage now, but it's gonna take ages as the transfer rate is veeeery low. Strange as the drive reports to run only slightly over 6,200 hours which is far from its average runtime. Of course I do know that some issues created this average, otherwise it would have thousand of zeros... ;)

Comment: `chkdsk` is as good at finding hard drive errors as opening the box and looking at it.

Comment: Chkdisk and co will work fine on truly ancient drives. Modern drives (ald older SCSI drives) however will 'fix' problems on their own. If that fix (a sector reallocation) works then no error will be reported back to chkdsk. It will just take a lot longer while the drive tries to read a sector over and over until it succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the [Acronis drive monitor](http://acronis.com/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor) to confirm that it is OK. It's free.

**EDIT** As per your comments on the original post you got a message similar to "Degradated" ... I suggest you back up and replace the hard drive.